# Twitter bootstrap project structure

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

The biggest dilemma I face before every project is whether I need to use the whole of Bootstrap or just the required parts of it. I wasted a lot of time deciding on this.

My setups so far have been like this:

Copy the less directory from twitter/bootstrap to my stylesheets directory

```
├── bootstrap
│   ├── layouts.less
│   └── more...
├── fonts.less
├── mixins.less
├── mysite.less
├── plugins.less
└── variables.less
```

Create a `plugins.less` file to include required bootstrap less files. It will look like this:

```
  @import "bootstrap/layouts.less";
  @import "bootstrap/type.less";
  @import "bootstrap/forms.less";
  @import "bootstrap/buttons.less";
  @import "bootstrap/utilities.less";
```

Then, use this plugins.less inside my `main.less` file.

```
  @import "fonts.less"
  @import "variables.less"     // Bootstrap's + my variables
  @import "mixins.less"        // Bootstrap's + my mixins
  @import "plugins.less"
  @import "mysite.less"
```

From the blog posts and discussions I have seen, it looks like most people just include bootstrap.css, bootstrap-responsive.css and overwrite styles with custom.css. While I understand that this will minimize the "bootstrap"ping time of a project, I worry about bloat and maintenance. When I use this method, I see, through the Inspector, hundreds of styles being overridden. Also, I may accidentally use a class name used by bootstrap.

Are there any disadvantages to the method I use? Or should I just use http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html and override some classes in `custom.less`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I include the less files required for my project and then customize the given classes to do what I need. If I need to add custom classes, I do it in custom.less.

Each project is different though, so make Bootstrap work for you. Is the site going to be maintained for many years? Perhaps you want to take the time to remove unused less files and modify existing classes to do what you need. If the project needs to be done quickly and perhaps the site will be short lived, just include all the .less file and overwrite in custom.less

It might also be useful to know that in Bootstrap version 3, all of the less will be in one file http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2012/12/10/bootstrap-3-plans/. Personally I like working with one large file instead of working with many .less files.

Answer (score 0):

This is how my setup looks like:

```
|-bootstrap (as cloned from github)
|
|-css
| |-app.css
| |-app.less (watched by LESS compiler)
|
|-js
| |-app.js
| |-plugins
|
|-img
|  
|-index.html
```

I include the bootstrap files in my app.less file, which I compile invoking the less compiler from terminal, to app.css (I link this one in my html templates)

This way I can safely upgrade bootstrap anytime (with a simple `git pull` in bootstrap folder)

Answer (score 0):

instead of overwriting you can specify your styles in classes and use those classes wherever you need to use that style. This way you will not mess up with overwriting many styles and mixing with existing bootstrap classes. you can use namepsacing like this.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default pn-navabr">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    // Inner code
  </div>
</div> 

.pn-navabr{    // Pn is project name initials, you can choose anything you like maybe dev's name initials 

}
.pn-navabr .navabr-inner{   

}
```

This way you can really clean up your css and make it really scalable without messing up and overriding bootstrap core. and you will always have flexibility to use Sass, Less, mix or pure css.